# Vue looking for data property on class based component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having an issue with VueJs looking for the `data` property on a TypeScript-based class component.

I have the following very simple component:

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class ExampleComponent extends Vue {
public personModel: PersonModel;
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.personModel = new PersonModel();
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error in my browser:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance
> but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

I have looked at other tickets, which suggest using the constructor to initialise the property, which I have done, but this does not help.

When I debug in Chrome, you can see that Vue is still looking at `_vm.data.personModel`. `data` is `undefined` of course, and my understanding is that with with class based approach, I should not need to have `data` defined.

[image: debugger screenshot]

Any insights into what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: put an `!` after person, `public person!: PersonModel`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sorry that doesn't help. That only seems to be for properties not data items and is to specify that a nullable var cannot be null when used.

Comment: Where are you using `ExampleComponent`? It looks like you've defined the field as `person` but are attempting to access it as `personModel`

Comment: @wormania, Sorry it's just a very cut down example for clarity on the site, So I also renamed a few things. I have updated the question. Good spot but it's not the problem. BTW I am routing to it via a to:= attribute from a v-list-tile on a sidebar

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your template?